# Changing the complete shell script program to awk

Tags: shell, awk

I am using a shell script program which internally calls an awk script ... But I am planning to change the entire script to awk as I am having some problems .. I just want to know that there are some commands in shell which I would like to know if they can be done in awk.

1) ls, cd, zcat .. If I am able to do it, How can I do .. Could you ppl please get some suggestions regarding this. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you describe what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Shell commands and external utilities such as those you list can be performed by the AWK `system()` function. You may not need `cd` and `ls` depending on what you're doing. Something like `zcat` can be called with `system()` and the output read using `getline`.

```
cmd = "zcat filename"
while ((cmd | getline) > 0 {
    # do something with the data
}
close(cmd)
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is a programming resource.  The questions that get the best answers tend to include source code, input data, expected results and actual results.  You will get better answers if you TRY to do things, fail, then come here with specific questions.

That said, you can find out what commands are available within awk by running `man awk` from your shell.  In general, you should keep in mind that `ls` and `zcat` and anything in /bin or /usr/bin are also not "built-in" to your shell, but are external programs that can be called from an interactive command line or a script in most languages.  To be clear: `ls` and `zcat` are not part of awk, and are also not part of /bin/sh.

There are also different versions of awk, with different behaviours and different commands available.  You will get the best documentation from your own system, since we don't know what tools you're using.

So ... for this question, show us your shell script, show us your attempt to make it an awk script, ask questions about specific problems you're having.  Without seeing your code, we have no way of knowing whether what you want to do is even possible in shell, let alone awk.